# Delphi + Message Queue

Tags: delphi, jms, message-queue, mq

Are there any free solutions to use [Message Queueing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_queue) with Delphi?

I just know about [Habari](http://www.habarisoft.com/habari.html) (which is not free) but could not find free solutions on the internet.

---

About the votes to close my topic. 
I'm asking a question, if I need to explain here what it is, probably I'll not know how to answer. People that know what I was talking about could answer without problems, like Daniele and Jeroen Pluimers.

But for those that don't know what is a MQ:
Here you can learn the basic of it: http://mq.java.net/overview.html
After learn what it is you can read about the brokers as: ActiveMQ, HornetQ, GlassFish, RabbitMQ etc...
And as now you know, we need a client to talk with the brokers, is this client that I'm searching for, in this case one of the options (few options) is http://www.habarisoft.com/habari_openmq.html.

Tks

Comment: I have no idea what this question is about.

Comment: Me neither.  You should probably provide a bit more context or this is likely to get closed.

Comment: The only "Habari" Google finds is a bogging platform. I don't thing that's a Message Queue. You know what? Count me in with a vote to close for "not a real question".

Comment: Habari: http://www.habarisoft.com/habari.html

Comment: Guys, I know the English used by OP was not well, but the combination of "MQ", "Habari" and "free" should have given users with a 3000+ rep enough clues on what this question was about. Voted for re-open. SO is not about raiding bad questions, but on improving them and building a community.

Comment: @SaCi: What MQ platform are you using? Or are you still considering an MQ platform? Many MQ platforms are open source, but the Delphi interfaces are not. The Delphi interfaces by Habari are good and worth their money. I have used their ActiveMQ to my satisfaction. In the past, I have written wrappers for IBM AS/400 message queueing; it is a lot of work which you should try to avoid.

Comment: Jeroen, tks for your reply. I'm searching for the best solution to me. I'm doing some tests on HornetQ or ActiveMQ, I know that I'll need a lot of performance and what I found on internet is that HornetQ is better in this point. I'm really thinking to buy Habari, first 'cause there are not much options, second 'cause of your indication now. 
Like you said to implement a client all again is to much work and it is not the focus of my company.
tks

Comment: saci Did you repost this asking about JMS using a different ID? You should have just EDITED this one, and it would be reopened.

Comment: No, I didn't repost and I didn't have other id.
And I already decided what to do. I'll buy Habari, I have other guys on my team that was searching for this too, maybe one of them.
tks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If stomp is ok for you try my stomp client at www.danieleteti.it

Comment: Daniele, is with happiness that I see you reply here. 
I was studying your implementation yesterday, I got some problems while working on Delphi 2007. The Demos didn't compile, the calls to functions of the client was different, I think that it's 'cause the implementation was created by lazarus. I changed to similar functions of the Delphi implementation and it worked. 
But I got some other problems, on the examples instances of the type TStompClient get nil with out any calls to free it (that I could see, only something internal can do it). If you'd like I can detail it by e-mail. 
tks

Comment: I'll accept your answer 'cause I asked for free alternatives and yours is the only stomp client that I found. Tks

Comment: @SaCi Update from the svn please. If you still find problems, add an issue in the google code project. Thanks for using my stomp client.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for the free WebSphere MQ client, it's [SupportPac MQC7](http://bit.ly/SupportPacMQC7).  If you are looking for something else, you will need to be more specific.